# Area 51 Rendering Bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, firefox

I'm using Firefox 3.6.3 for Ubuntu 10.04 and sometimes some of the on-topic/off-topic votes look weird:

[alt text http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/4405/screenshotvt.png](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/4405/screenshotvt.png)

It only happens sometimes, if I refresh the page it usually fixes itself. The rest of the page looks fine. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: There are rendering bugs all over the place (well, three places anyway) with IE7, but I haven't reported them because I can't post screenshots.

Comment: For the record, I get this in Firefox 3.6 on Mac, too. Haven't noticed if I'm getting it on Windows yet.

Comment: Looks great in Chrome 6!

Comment: I get the same using FF3.6.3 on win7-x64

Comment: I already reported this error via e-mail before the site went public to Meta.